# sshfs - can't unmount the point

Tags: filesystems, mount, sshfs, unmounting

I mounted a folder on a remote machine using `sshfs`, but didn't specify `-o allow_other` flag thus can't access the mounted directory.

When I try to mount over with `-o allow_other` option `sshfs` gives me this error:

> mount: according to mtab, xxx is already mounted on yyy

To allow mounting over existing mount points I specified `-o nonempty` - but with no luck - got the same error as above.

When I try to unmount the mount point:

> fusermount -u mountpoint

I get the error:

> entry for yyy not found in /etc/mtab

So, what do I do to unmount the incorrectly mounted point?

Comment: What's mount output?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh user@remotemachine:path on yyy type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,max_read=65536)

Comment: @Mitten - can you move that output into the Q? It's hard to follow what it's doing.

Comment: `mount -a`  , however you got your answer.

Comment: *Entry for yyy not found in /etc/mtab* can also mean that you misspelled the path of the mount point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the filesystem is already mounted and you need to change the mount options, you must remount the filesystem. You can either `umount` then `mount` or you can use the `remount` option to mount. Here is an example:

```
mount -t sshfs -o remount,allow_other foo:/bar /some/path
```

Comment: Is it mounted if he can't `fusermount -u mountpoint`?

Comment: @slm His `mount` and `fusermount` commands do contradict each other.

Comment: sudo unmount yyy did the trick. when executing unmount yyy under non-root it was producing the error: unmount: yyy is not in the fstab (and you are not root) so I sudo-ed the command and viola - it worked!

Comment: @TomHale Change `sshfs` to the file system type that you are trying to remount eg `ext4`

Comment: I needed `mount -t fuse.sshfs ...`.